# Component selector in Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm trying to select multiple objects (2 labels & 2 textfields) that are located in a panel. I gave these components a property (changeVisibility: true).

So the thing i'm trying to accomplish here is quite simple: when the user checks the checkbox, all the components with the property (changeVisibility:true) should become invisible. So in my controller i'm trying to select these components but i'm unable to accomplish this thusfar.

Help is much appreciated!

Code of my panel:

```
Ext.define('Edocs.view.wizard.card-2.content.mobile-password.Panel', {
extend : 'Ext.FormPanel',
alias : 'widget.mobilePassword',
layout : {
    type : 'vbox',
    pack: 'center'
},
bodyStyle:{"background-color":"beige"},
border:false,
defaults:{

    width: '100%'     
},

items: [{        
    xtype           : 'checkboxfield',
    boxLabel        : 'Enable mobile (iphone) accesibility',
    boxLabelAlign   : 'before',
    name            : 'enableMobile',
    inputValue      : '1',
    id              : 'cbxMobile',
    itemId          : 'cbxMobile'

},{
    xtype: 'label',
    text: "Please enter a password to connect to the platform by mobile (iphone/ipad)",
    style: 'font-weight:bold;',
    changeVisibility :true
},{
    xtype: 'textfield', 
    name: 'mobilePassword',
    id: 'txtMobilePassword',
    inputType: 'password'  ,
    changeVisibility :true
    //width: '100%'
},{
    xtype: 'label',
    text: "Confirm password",
    style: 'font-weight:bold;',
    changeVisibility :true
},
{
    xtype: 'textfield', 
    name: 'mobilePasswordConfirm',
    itemId: 'txtMobilePasswordConfirm',
    inputType: 'password'  ,
    vtype: 'password',
    initialPassField: 'txtMobilePassword',
    changeVisibility :true
}],


initComponent : function() {

    Ext.apply(this, {})
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

This is the function in my controller (this function is called on the change event of the checkbox):

```
addMobilePassword : function(checkbox) {
    var items = checkbox.up().down('mobilePassword[changeVisibility=true]');
    if (checkbox.checked){
        for (var i in items){
            items[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having troubles with this selector:

```
 var items = checkbox.up().down('mobilePassword[changeVisibility=true]');
```

If anyone could give me some advice on how to select these components.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [checkbox.up().query('mobilePassword[changeVisibility=true]')](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-query)?

Comment: Just tried and didn't work...

Comment: I know that if the components would only be labels this should work:   var items = checkbox.up().down('label[changeVisibility=true]');

Comment: But in my case i need labels & textfields and i don't know how to select multiple types of components...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`down()` will find the first matched descendant of the container. So I think you should try:

```
checkbox.up().down('mobilePassword').query('label[changeVisibility], textfield[changeVisibility]')
```

or briefer

```
checkbox.up().query('label[changeVisibility], textfield[changeVisibility]')
```

Comment: Just a remark, to get all components with changeVisibility attribute, regardless of their type you can also use: `.query('*[changeVisibility]')`

Answer (score 0):

Try `query('[changeVisibility=true]')`

Comment: Doesn't work either :( (And btw, it should be Ext.query because an error is thrown if you only type query)

Comment: Well duh... You should still use `checkbox.up().` before the query method. What I was trying to show you - if you specify `mobilePassword` before `[]` it will try to look for objects with type mobilePassword which is not what you wanted

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. But it's still not working.. I tried it without any luck